# Is there any way that I can show My CheckBox calculation Answer on same page in using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a calculator using checkbox and simple javascript but is not showing multiple answers at same time at the page.
it show only one answer at one time not multiple
and when i check divistion than correctly work but when select another like addition than it not showing any answers.
and also the console is not showing anther answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Building Claculator Using Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f" id="f1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Value 1 :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Value 2 :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Choose Any Option :-</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="div">Divition(/)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="mult">Multiplication(*)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="add">Addition(+)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="sub">Subtraction(-)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Answer" onclick="show()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p id="p1"></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        
        function show(){
            let n1 = parseInt(document.f.n1.value);
            let n2 = parseInt(document.f.n2.value);
            console.log(n1);
            console.log(n2);
            let val = ''
            let msg = "The Answer of "
            let call = document.f
            for(let i=0;i<call.v.length;i++){
             
                if(document.f.v[i].checked){    
                    val = document.f.v[i].value
                    console.log(val)
                    if(val == 'div'){
                        let ans = n1 / n2
                        msg += "Division : "
                        console.log(ans);
                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML +=  (msg + ans)
                    }
                    if(val == 'mul'){
                        let ans = n1 * n2
                        msg += "Multiplication : "
                        console.log(ans)
                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = (msg + ans)
                    }
                    if(val == 'add'){
                        let ans = n1 + n2
                        msg += "Addition : "
                        console.log(ans)
                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = (msg + ans)
                    }
                    if(val == 'sub'){
                        let ans = n1 - n2
                        msg += "Subtraction : "
                        console.log(ans)
                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = (msg + ans)
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make this a runnable example, easier to see and answer.

Comment: One issue: you check `val == 'mul'` but the value is `mult`

Answer (score 1):

You could make a global variable where to store the responses, and make a console.log to that variable after each iteration of the function, that is, after each multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate your output string in the other calculations. I've used the `msg` variable to store all of the responses then outputting it one time to the `p1` inner html.

Your original code was concatinating the p1 inner html with the answer in the division condition (using the `+=`), but not on any of the other conditions.

Also, you had the option value for multiplication set to "mult" rather than "mul".

```js
function show(){
    
    let n1 = parseInt(document.f.n1.value);
    let n2 = parseInt(document.f.n2.value);
    console.log(n1);
    console.log(n2);

    let val = ''
    let msg = "The Answer of "
    let call = document.f
    for(let i=0;i<call.v.length;i++){
     
        if(document.f.v[i].checked){    
            val = document.f.v[i].value
            console.log(val)
            if(val == 'div'){
                let ans = n1 / n2
                msg += "Division : " + ans;
                console.log(ans);
            }
            if(val == 'mul'){
                let ans = n1 * n2;
                msg += "Multiplication : " + ans;
                console.log(ans)
            }
            if(val == 'add'){
                let ans = n1 + n2
                msg += "Addition : " + ans;
                console.log(ans)
            }
            if(val == 'sub'){
                let ans = n1 - n2
                msg += "Subtraction : " + ans;
                console.log(ans)
            }
        }
        

    }

    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Building Claculator Using Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f" id="f1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Value 1 :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Value 2 :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="n2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Choose Any Option :-</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="div">Divition(/)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="mul">Multiplication(*)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="add">Addition(+)<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="v" value="sub">Subtraction(-)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Answer" onclick="show()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p id="p1"></p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```